# $f(x)=3x+4$ - Injective and Surjective?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

As a follow-up to [Understanding why $f(x)=2x$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283700/prove-fx-2x-is-injective), I'm working on proving/disproving that $$f(x)=3x+4,$$ where inputs/outputs live on real numbers, is injective and surjective.

Supposing that $$f(a)=f(b),$$ then $$3a+4=3b+4.$$

Solve for $0$:

$$3a+4-4-3b=0$$
$$3(a-b)=0$$

So, $a$ must equal $b$. Therefore, $f$ is injective.

With respect to whether it's surjective, I looked at its graph:

[image: Source-WolframAlpha]

Since $$3x + 4$$ is linear, then it's continuous, I believe. As a result, is that proof enough that it's surjective, i.e. for all $x$ in $$f(x),$$ the output will cover all real numbers?

Comment: Don't forget to also format for latex in your titles.  And don't forget to put your punctuation *inside* the dollar signs when you use *double dollars*, otherwise it formats the punctuation by itself on the following line.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I'll be more careful in future posts.

Comment: No one says 'Solve for $0$'. 'Solve for' is only used for when you want to find a variable in an equation. You can say, given an equation with $x$ as a variable, 'solve for $x$', which would mean 'find $x$ expressed as an expression independent of $x$'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would structure your proofs like so.

**Claim:** The mapping $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=3x+4$ is injective.

*Proof.* Let $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ and suppose $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then
$$
f(x_1) = f(x_2)\\[0.5em]
3x_1+4 = 3x_2+4\\[0.5em]
3x_1=3x_2\\[0.5em]
x_1=x_2.
$$
Thus, the mapping is injective. $\blacksquare$

**Claim:** The mapping $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=3x+4$ is surjective.

*Proof.* Suppose $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then let $x=\frac{y-4}{3}$. We have the following:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 3x+4\\[0.5em]
&= 3\left(\frac{y-4}{3}\right)+4\\[1em]
&= (y-4)+4\\[0.5em]
&= y.
\end{align}
Thus, the mapping is surjective. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

You can prove directly that $f$ is surjective.

Suppose $y\in\mathbb R$. Can we find an $x\in\mathbb R$ with $f(x)=y$?

$$3x+4 = y \iff 3x = y-4 \iff x = \tfrac13 y - \tfrac43$$

and that's certainly a real number if $x$ is, so we're done.

Comment: @Adayah: Yes, I'm not sure how continuity alone helps, as It is neither necessary nor sufficient to show surjectivity without additional hypotheses.

Comment: OP probably wanted to connect it with the fact that $f[ \mathbb{R} ]$ is unbounded from below and above and use Darboux property, which makes for some proof.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose to the contrary that some real number $r$ was not in its image.

But $x = \frac{r-4}{3}$ is equal to that number $r$.

Comment: Could you please say what `iage` means?

Comment: @KevinMeredith It was a typo. It was meant to say image.

Answer (score 0):

To show surjectivity, reason as follows:

Suppose $f(x)$ is some arbitrary number $y$.  Is there an $x$ I can plug in to $f$ that will produce that number $y$ ?

In your case this amounts to solving $y=3x+4$ for $x$, which will show that the answer is yes.

Since $y$ was an arbitrary number, you have shown that any real number will be hit by $f$, which means it is surjective.